# Count from column in a table by referencing a column in another table

Tags: database, postgresql, select

I wasn't really sure what to title this but this is what I'm trying to do:

I have a table of teams:

```
teamid | city | name
```

and I have a table of games played:

```
gameid | teamid | points
```

What I'm trying to do is tally the total points scored in all games played by the 'Raptors'.

I've tried it this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(points) AS "Raptors Points" FROM TEAMS, GAMES 
    WHERE name = 'Raptors' AND TEAMS.teamid = GAMES.teamid;
```

and this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(points) AS "Raptors Points" FROM (SELECT * FROM 
    TEAMS JOIN GAMES ON TEAMS.teamid = GAMES.teamid WHERE 
    name = 'Raptors') AS foo;
```

Both result in a table displaying only points from one of the games (the first one) instead of a total count from all games.

I'm really stumped as to what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are seeing the wrong value and thinking it's a proper value.  You need to change `COUNT(points)` with `SUM(points)`

Count will give you the total number of records, SUM will give you the total number of points

BTW your first query should work if you fix that